# Using a layout inside a layout?

Tags: android, layout, button

Which is the best way to change the content inside a layout by pressing buttons?
I want 6 buttons and different content for each push.

I cannot use tab layout because i already used it so..

Comment: Unless you feel view is cluttered, you can use tab layout. Technically it is possible.

Comment: This question is a bit vague...

Could you provide a screenshot of what you currently have and better describe what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the gridview that is set up in API Demos. You can import it in as a new project from the Android SDK.

It works effectively like the list of 'All Apps'. However you can change the way it lays out the buttons/icons/text.

Answer (score 0):

In an app I'm working on, I have a list of message types as buttons. Clicking a button changes the display to a layout for composing the selected message. To do this, I have a FrameLayout for the area I want to change. I reference this view as 'compose_content'. When I want to change the content, I run the following code:

```
compose_content.removeAllViews();
LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.new_content,compose_content, true);
```

This will change the FrameLayout content to the content from the specified layout.

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be to have all the 6 views inside your inflated xml and depending on the button pressed set the visibility of that particular view visible and the rest gone